# C# - WP7 WebBrowser Navigating Event Handler

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, event-handling, browser

I cannot figure out how to catch the Navigating event on the WebBrowser control. Basically I'm trying to figure out how trigger the progress bar to show when a user clicks a link on a page.

Here is the code I use to show the progress bar and then hide it on page loaded. Can someone help me out with the event handler for Navigating?

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
        progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(MY_URL, UriKind.Absolute));
        webBrowser.LoadCompleted += new System.Windows.Navigation.LoadCompletedEventHandler(PageLoadCompleted);
        webBrowser.Navigating = ?
    }
    private void PageLoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
        progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you seek [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigating%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). You can write

```
webBrowser.Navigating += webBrowser_Navigating;
// ...

void webBrowser_Navigating( object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e )
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: A tad late, but this should be: += new EventHandler<NavigatingEventArgs>(webBrowser_Navigating);

Comment: @jyavenard, actually, no, you don't need to instatiate the EventHandler<> explicitly. The C# compiler will write that for you. It can do that because there is nothing else (no other type) that delegate can be. All other things being equal, I always prefer to write less code so that my intentions are clearer and not lost in extra clutter.

Comment: That is right, however, this is the code self generated by VS whenever you start the code. So I figured it's the proper way to do it :)

Comment: To be clear, the code is generated by the C# compiler (not Visual Studio), and it is done when you compile the code, not when the code is run (started). The C# product team added auto-implemented delegates specifically so that you don't have to write redundant code. There are several such features in C# 3.0 and beyond to reduce the amount of code you have to write, such as auto-implemented properties, lambdas, type inference, and so on. Let the compiler do this work for you, rather than duplicate what the compiler will write unless you have a need to write something different.

Comment: Another late comment, but I think he meant the code that is suggested by Visual Studio when you start typing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of by [VisualStuart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1019277/visual-stuart) helped me solve my problem.

My now working code is as below :

```
private void MyButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyprogressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
    MyprogressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    string site = MyTextBox1.Text;
    webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(site, UriKind.Absolute));
    webBrowser1.Navigating += webBrowser1_Navigating;
    webBrowser1.LoadCompleted += new System.Windows.Navigation.LoadCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_LoadCompleted);
}

private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    MyTextBox1.Text = e.Uri.ToString();
    MyprogressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
    MyprogressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```